# Greedy feature selection for predication in r

Tags: r, feature-selection, greedy

I'm new to R and I'm trying to choose the best feature in a dataset for predication. There are many features to choose from, however, it's quite of a lengthy process to run a model for each separate feature to compare the best predictors. I heard of the greedy feature selection but I'm not sure how it works.
I'd appreciate it if someone can help me find the right path or to provide me with the code.
Much appreciated!

Comment: Which machine learning methods are you currently using, and what do you mean by "greedy" feature selection?

Comment: I’ve been using Linear regression and Bayesian Ridge regression. I was told that the greedy feature selection is a way to run a model for selecting the best feature for prediction out of multiple features in a dataset.

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for a way to find the best feature for prediction out of multiple features in a dataset.

Comment: I have some familiarity with decision trees (random forests) and support vector machines.  Both of these methods would in fact give you precisely what you want, namely the best predictors in your data set.

Comment: I tried using random forests but I get this error every time and I'm not sure why "Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories."

Comment: How many predictors do you have?  Do you want this feature(s) to be treated numerically, or as a factor?

Comment: I have a total of 12 columns.

Comment: Why are you trying to determine the best variable? There are several ways to determine the "best" variable.